# Error in HttpResponse/httpClient.execute

Tags: java, android, httpconnection

I am new to Android and new to Stackoverflow!

I am just creating dummy app to learn http connection.
while compiling i encountered an error in this line

> HttpResponse getbackdata= http_client.execute(url_data);

I even searched in stackoverflow but mostly people out thr suggested to use Exception Handling to catch UnknownHostException . i did that. I dont know where i messed up with the code.
It might be a minor error since i am beginner i will learn from it. 
Thanks in Advance.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);         

        try {
            HttpClient http_client=new DefaultHttpClient();
            URI url=new URI("http://www.mysite.com");
            HttpGet url_data=new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse getbackdata= http_client.execute(url_data);

            InputStreamReader in =new InputStreamReader(getbackdata.getEntity().getContent());
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);

            StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer("");
            String info="";
            String nl=System.getProperty("line.separator");

            while((info=br.readLine())!=null){
                sb.append(info.toString()+nl);
            }
            br.close();
            TextView output=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.display_output);
            output.setText(sb.toString());
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.d("ARR_ERROR","UnknownHostException : "+e);
        }
         catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.d("ARR_ERROR","ClientProtocolException : "+e);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.d("ARR_ERROR","IOException : "+e);
        }
         catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.d("ARR_ERROR","URISyntaxException : "+e);
    }


}
```

Comment: Use Asynchronous class. Post logcat.

Comment: I wonder why freaking people downvote my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me guess, you are getting a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`, right? Use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for your network tasks. Don't do them on the UI thread.

Answer (score 2):

NOTE: You can't update your data  on Main UI thread.

For that you have to use **AsyncTask** or **Thread with Handler** and update your data with **runOnUiThread()** method.

You can go with this also:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html